# How to print {{something}} in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular js reads and interpret what written in  " {{code}} " and removes these curly braces. I want to show these curly braces, irrespective of what it is containing. I dont care about the code, all i need to show are these {{ }} brackets. Plus, if there is any escape sequence then do tell me.

Comment: Are you saying you want to just wrap all expressions in `{{}}`?  E.g. `test = "nick"` -> `{{test}}` -> output : `{{nick}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code

```
{{ '\{\{ \}\}' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-non-bindable`.
Like this:

`<div ng-non-bindable>{{1+2}}</div>`

And it will output `{{1+2}}`.

Comment: and how to do without using ng-non-bindable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngNonBindable` directive:

```
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div>
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```

Here is the documentation for 
[Angular ngNonBindable documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

> The ngNonBindable directive tells Angular not to compile or bind the contents of the current DOM element. This is useful if the element contains what appears to be Angular directives and bindings but which should be ignored by Angular. This could be the case if you have a site that displays snippets of code, for instance.

Comment: I am looking for a hack. I know using ng-non-bindable would work. But how to do without using it as it was asked in one competition.